# Prolog add function

Tags: prolog

I am a newbie in Prolog. I have this facts:

```
user(alice). 
user(bob).
money(alice,10).
money(bob,20).
```

The facts means that alice have 10 dollars and bob 20 dollars. In order to learn Prolog, i want to develop a function to transfer money between two users. My function should take in input the name of the receiver and the amount and add the quantity to the receiver.

```
example: add(alice,20)
```

and the output should be 30.
Actually my function is:

```
add(X,Y,Z) :- Z is money(X,M) + Y.
```

but it doesn't work.

How i can implement it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as you want to modify the facts for the predicate `money/2` as the users exchange money, you need to declare the predicate dynamic:

```
:- dynamic(money/2).
```

Second, as Prolog is a *relational* language, not a *functional* language, you cannot write expressions as `Z is money(X,M)`. Instead you need to write something like:

```
add(User, Money) :-
    % remove old clause and access how much money the user holds
    retract(money(User, Current)),
    % compute the updated amount of money the user will be holding
    Updated is Current + Money,
    % add updated fact
    assertz(money(User, Updated).
```